# Set space between boxplots in Python Graphs generated nested box plots with Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, seaborn

I am trying to set a space between the boxplots (between the green and orange boxes) created with Python [`Seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org) module's [`sns.boxplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html). Please see attached the graph, that the green and orange subplot boxes are stuck to each other, making it visually not the most appealing.

Can't find a way to do that, anyone could find a way (code attached)?

[image: Seaborn Boxplots]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.set(style="ticks", palette='Set2', font='Roboto Condensed')
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.1, rc={"lines.linewidth": 1.1})
g=sns.factorplot(x="time", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
               col="day", data=tips, kind="box", size=4, aspect=0.5,
                 width=0.8,fliersize=2.5,linewidth=1.1, notch=False,orient="v")
sns.despine(trim=True)
g.savefig('test6.png', format='png', dpi=600)
```

The `Seaborn` boxplot documentation is here: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

Answer (score 2):

Running the danger that this is not needed anymore, I found a solution to this problem. When drawing `boxplots` directly with matplotlib, the arrangement of the boxes can be controlled with the `width` and `position` keywords. However, when passing the `positions` keyword to `sns.factorplot(kind='box',...)`, one gets a

```
TypeError: boxplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'positions'
```

To get around this, one can set the widths of the boxes 'manually' *after* the boxplot has been created. This is a bit tedious, because the boxes are stored as `PatchPatches` within the individual `Axes` instances of the `FacedGrid` that is returned by `sns.factorplot`. Instead of the simple `(x,y,width,height)` syntax that `Rects` have, `PathPatches` use vertices to define the corners, which involves slightly more computation when one wants to adjust the boxes. On top of everything else, the `PathPatches` returned by `matplotlib.boxplot` contain an extra (ignored) vertex for the `Path.CLOSEPOLY` code, which is set to `(0,0)` and is best ignored. In addition to the box, the horizontal line that marks the median is now too wide and needs to be adjusted as well.

Below I define a function that adjusts widths of the boxes generated by the OP's example code(note the extra import):

```
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
def adjust_box_widths(g, fac):
    """
    Adjust the withs of a seaborn-generated boxplot.
    """

    ##iterating through Axes instances
    for ax in g.axes.flatten():

        ##iterating through axes artists:
        for c in ax.get_children():

            ##searching for PathPatches
            if isinstance(c, PathPatch):
                ##getting current width of box:
                p = c.get_path()
                verts = p.vertices
                verts_sub = verts[:-1]
                xmin = np.min(verts_sub[:,0])
                xmax = np.max(verts_sub[:,0])
                xmid = 0.5*(xmin+xmax)
                xhalf = 0.5*(xmax - xmin)

                ##setting new width of box
                xmin_new = xmid-fac*xhalf
                xmax_new = xmid+fac*xhalf
                verts_sub[verts_sub[:,0] == xmin,0] = xmin_new
                verts_sub[verts_sub[:,0] == xmax,0] = xmax_new

                ##setting new width of median line
                for l in ax.lines:
                    if np.all(l.get_xdata() == [xmin,xmax]):
                        l.set_xdata([xmin_new,xmax_new])
```

calling this function with

```
adjust_box_widths(g, 0.9)
```

gives the following output:

[image: seaborn boxplot with adjusted box width]