# Using Seaborn to label values on a two level cateogrical boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I would like to add median values to a boxplot in Seaborn where there are two levels of categorical data on the x-axis.  How would I do this?

I saw this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649501/labeling-boxplot-in-seaborn-with-median-value) and applied it to my problem, but due to the positioning of labels reliant on `ax.get_xticklabels`, the median values of the first four values are applied in the middle of the outer categorical variable.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
medians = \
    tips.groupby(['day', 'smoker']).agg({'total_bill':np.median}).values
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips)
pos = range(len(medians))
for tick,label in zip(pos,ax.get_xticklabels()):
    ax.text(pos[tick], medians[tick] + 0.5, medians[tick],\
    horizontalalignment='center', size='small')
```

[image]

Comment: One way to do it would be to look for the positions of the vertical lines and align the labels with that. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48541304/2454357) is not terribly related, but should give you an idea how to get hold of these lines. I would imagine looping through `ax.lines` and look for the ones where the `x` values don't change.

Comment: Looks like the more severe problem is that the values are not actually correct.